# Call HTTPS SOAP service

Tags: java, soap

I want to call a HTTPS SOAP web service with sslFactory. I have used below code.

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSslFactory (sslFactory);
HttpURLConnection.setDefaultHostVerifiers(hostVerifier).
```

It's working but other HTTPS APIs are not calling so my application is not running because of this as it is static method. So I alternatively tried to use `HttpsURLConnection con = url.openConnection();`
Can anyone give a proper solution to call a SOAP service with HTTPS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.